# NumberFormat allow zero or two digists?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I use Java NumberFormat like this:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
format.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
String number = format.format(price);
```

When the double value is: 19.95 I get 19,95 localized correctly to German format. 
When the double value is: 19.5 I get 19,5 which is a wrong format.

If a price is 19.50 I need to get exactly two digists, i.e., 19,50.
If a price is 19.00 I need to get zero digists, i.e., 19.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Tried [`setMinimumFractionDigits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits(int))?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider This is wrong. If there are no digists I do not want to display any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    double price = <your price>;
    int priceAsInt = (int)price;
    if(((double)priceAsInt) == price) {
        String number = String.valueOf(priceAsInt);
        System.out.println(number);
    } else {
        String number = format.format(price);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.